# phpmyadmin auto increment primary key act strange

Tags: phpmyadmin, primary-key

I use phpmyadmin to add row to my database using 'insert' (insérer in french) button. but instead of auto increment of one more than the last row my primary key is incremented of a lot of more.

For exemple I was at the primary key 29, add a row and it number is 600

Is there is a way to change things ?
Is this normal ? 
Can I do something to modify this ?

I am new to this program so I am a litttle lost.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Operations for this table and you should be able to see under "Table options" the next auto-increment value.

Comment: Thanks I hope it will fix it. I didn't know this option